# @media with width: 100%

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I'm attempting to use @media tags to replace the photo displayed by an element when the element reaches a certain width, I originally had the width set to 100%, however, I've read that it could cause responsiveness issues so I changed it to max-width and min-width, however, no change anyway here is the code.

Note: I checked the width of the element using inspect element on chrome and .container was reaching 767px on a downscale so I don't think the element not changing width is the problem

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    
  .container {
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/214519/pexels-photo-214519.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  };
};
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 767px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/159146/train-cargo-bow-river-banff-159146.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
<div class="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Medias are for the screen size, not for elements sizes

Comment: @Maxwells.c yes that's true however the goal is for say someone is using an iPhone, they will have 'x' image loaded while someone on desktop will have 'y' image loaded. I'm using media as a method to detect screen size and edit css based on the screen size

Comment: try to set `screen` instead of `only screen`. And you don't need to use min/max-width, you can use 100%;

Comment: @Maxwells.c I've been doing some experimenting and it's literally not reading the second media tag. I've been changing all of the tags inside of the second and first tag however every single time it never reads the second media tag, only the first.

Comment: i've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your closing brackets (don't use `};`, use only `}`).

Also, you don't need to specify both min and max width.

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    
  .container {
    min-width: 768px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/214519/pexels-photo-214519.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 767px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/159146/train-cargo-bow-river-banff-159146.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
<div class="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I figured it out. The solution to this question [Multiple CSS @media conditions don't seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118385/multiple-css-media-conditions-dont-seem-to-be-working) for some reason fixed it, even though I already tried it. Here's the code

```css
body,html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 1000px){
    .container {
        background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/7882/light-bulb-light-old.jpg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width: 1920px){
    .container{
        background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/531321/pexels-photo-531321.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb');
        background-position: left center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    <body>
<div class="container"></div>
    </body>
</html>


<!-- since I created this in a full screen browser you have to make your broswer window pretty big to get it to change but it does work -->
```